# How to interchange Key/Value in PHP?

Tags: php, php-5.4

I've an array in the following format.

```
[records] => Array
    (
        [7] => Array
            (
                [available] => No
            )
        [8] => Array
            (
                [available] => No
            )            
        [9] => Array
            (
                [available] => No
            )
        [11] => Array
            (
                [available] => Yes
            )

    )
```

I need to interchange the **Yes/No** Values with the **Array keys(7,8,9,11)**. Normally a loop would do the trick. However, I would like to know whether any other methods are available other than looping so that I could drop off the plan for an additional looping.

Comment: What's wrong with using a loop?

Comment: You mean like `array_fill_keys`? but it does use loop inside anyway. So there's no gain.
Or maybe you mean like in functional languages where there's lazy evaluation thingy.

Comment: What's the exact expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code it's works for you.

```
$array=Array
    (
        [7] => Array
            (
                [available] => No
            )
        [8] => Array
            (
                [available] => No
            )            
        [9] => Array
            (
                [available] => No
            )
        [11] => Array
            (
                [available] => Yes
            )

    )
array_walk($array, function(&$value) {
    $value['available'] = "Yes";
});
```

also see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Comment: You've forgot the return statement. It should be return $value['available'] == "Yes";

Comment: No need to return it's work perfect try to `print_r($array)`.